# How to turn an SPST momentary push button into a momentary DPDT?

Tags: switches, button, toggle-switch

How to turn an SPST momentary push button into a DPDT? I would like to close 2 circuits at the same time. (From comments: I want to ground the reset circuit while getting a pin to HIGH on an Arduino like board.)

**SPST** [image: SPST PB]

**DPDT** [image: DPDT]

[Image source](http://musicfromouterspace.com/analogsynth_new/ELECTRONICS/switches.html).

Comment: You want the DPDT to also be momentary? Or are you asking, without saying, that you want it to toggle back and forth by remembering its last state?

Comment: @jonk, I also want it to be momentary.

Comment: Why can't you buy a DPDT switch? What are you trying to turn on or off? Cant you have the SPST switch simply turn something else on that closes your 2 circuits? This question is too vague.

Comment: @WesleyLee Trying to learn alternatives, I'm new and don't have bunch of components laying around + shops are close. how to "simply turn something else on that closes your 2 circuits"? I want to ground the reset circuit while getting a pin to HIGH on an arduino like board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info in your comments.  You do not want a DPDT switch, but a resistor and an invertor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjVqzk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: looks promising. just learned what a 7404 is and your circuit seems to fit my specific needs

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGZpRh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Use a relay to provide DPDT action from a single push-to-make pushbutton.*

The relay coil voltage should be the same as the supply, V+.

The contacts should be rated for > switching voltage and > switching current. In your case it is small signal so it may be more important to get gold-plated contacts which won't corrode and degrade the small signals.

Comment: That's a good alternative, thanks. I didn't even know there were DPDT relay. But can it also be done with simple components like capacitor or transistor?

Comment: It depends what you are switching but you have given us no clue about that. Edit your question with the details.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to keep the existing SPST momentary switch then here is how to convert it to a DPDT switching circuit.

[image]